# getting id of selected node in kendo Treeview

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui

Kendo UI experts Please help me..

I am new to Kendo ui. I want to return id of Selected node in kendo treeview in my code.
but it is returning only same node.

On selecting Node i want to return id of selected Node to my code, and in Code i am returning
child elements of that node.

is there any simple way of doing it??

Thanks in advance..

My Code

```
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo.treeview.min.js"></script>
<script>
    homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
            url: "@Url.Action("datasourcefortree", "Home")",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
            id: "ResourceID",
            hasChildren: true
            }
        }
    });

    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: homogeneous,
        dataTextField: "Resource"
    });

</script>
```

and code of datasourcefortree method of homecontroller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult datasourcefortree(int? NodeID)
{

    FNHSessionManager sessionManager = new FNHSessionManager(_connString, FNHSessionManager.DatabaseType.MsSql);
    FNHRepository repository = new FNHRepository(sessionManager);
    int nodevalue = 1;

    if (NodeID == null)
    {
        ResourceMaster tree = repository.RetrieveById(nodevalue);
        List node = new List{
            new ResourceMaster
            {
                ResourceID = tree.ResourceID,
                Resource=tree.Resource
            }
        };
        return Json(node, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        if (NodeID.HasValue)
        {
            nodevalue = NodeID.Value;
            IList childtreenode = repository.GetAllRecord(nodevalue);
            return Json(childtreenode, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return (null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Syntax fix

```
$("#treeview").getKendoTreeView().dataItem(e.node).id
```

Comment: If this answer is true (that it is true), mark as answer this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        select: function(e) {    
            alert($("#treeview").getKendoTreeView().dataItem(e.node).ResourceID);
        },
//... other code                          
});
```